# Android Wear Step Counter crashing app

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I was writing an app to read heart rate and step count using an android wear device. The heart rate sensor works properly but the step count is causing an issue. However, on commenting the listener for Step Counter and registering a null in onResume() the app works with heart rate sensor. I'm not getting any log regarding this otherwise I would have posted it here. Here's the code that I'm using

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private TextView mTextViewHeart, mTextViewStep;
    private Sensor mHeartRateSensor, mStepCounterSensor;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
                mTextViewHeart = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.value_heart);
                mTextViewStep = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.value_step);
            }
        });

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
        mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(heartListener, mHeartRateSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(stepListener, mStepCounterSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(heartListener, mHeartRateSensor);
    }

    SensorEventListener heartListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE) {
                if (event.values.length > 0) {
                    if (event.values[0] > 0.0f) {
                        mTextViewHeart.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light);
                        mTextViewHeart.setText(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
                        sendToHandheld(Math.round(event.values[0]), Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    SensorEventListener stepListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER) {
                if (event.values.length > 0) {
                    mTextViewStep.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_green_light);
                    mTextViewStep.setText(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
                    sendToHandheld(Math.round(event.values[0]), Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    private void sendToHandheld(final int val, final int type) {
        final PendingResult<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult> nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient);
        nodes.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult result) {
                final List<Node> nodes = result.getNodes();
                if (nodes != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
                        final Node node = nodes.get(i);
                        Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), "/" + type, ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(val).array());
                        Log.d("Sending", type + ":" + val);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Update**

Got the log somehow

```
06-15 11:46:02.342    3355-3355/com.hsc.fit E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hsc.fit, PID: 3355
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
            at com.hsc.fit.MainActivity$3.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:92)
            at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:405)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Am not sure about this, but was interested in this code. So, just googled a bit, you may check these links and compare against your code. One of the links contains code to do the logging as well. http://marctan.com/blog/2014/07/08/reading-heart-rate-data-from-samsung-gear-live/       https://gist.github.com/mjohnsullivan/557c2f19ba177312b1d7

Comment: @gansai, thanks for the links. I've already seen the first one. In the second one the code is basically doing the same thing as my code, but the problem is that the app is crashing, so the Log code wont work. Also, I'm not getting the crash log either, making it difficult to debug.

Comment: Looks like mTextViewStep is becoming null sometimes (dont know why) and due to this, whenever sensor data changes, when you want to set mTextViewStep with its values, it throws this exception. Suggestion: you may log a warning if mTextViewStep is null, by adding a check and if mTextViewStep is not null, then set the values. This might temporarily avoid crashing the app

Comment: Yeah, even I'm confused why the text view is becoming null. For the time being I'm directly sending the data to my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The `WatchViewStub`'s `setOnLayoutInflatedListener()` is called after `onResume()`, and my Sensor gets registered in `onResume()`. Since my text view is used in the listener of the sensor, and it wasn't assigned a refrence yet, I was getting a `NullPointerException`. I moved the sensor registertion inside `WatchViewStub`'s listener and it works now.